# Angularjs ui-router home route

Tags: angularjs

I use ui-router plugin (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) with angularjs. And here is the code fragment:

```
$stateProvider.state('home', {
            url: '',
            controller: function() { console.log('home controller'); },
            onEnter: console.log('home onEnter')
        });
```

When url is '/' I get only "home onEnter" message in the console, and when url is empty I get both. Why it happens? Is there any difference between '/' and '' ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned and/or believe in strict SEO guidelines, you should consider it different.

Does the controller fire for both addresses?  Excluding SEO, I dont see any issue. Perhaps if you use $location.$$path it could be a problem, although I would suggest to avoid basing any logic on such methods.

Comment: I'm not concerned about SEO at all, I'm just struggling with angular and trying to understand how things work. For example, if I write three different states like home, user and files, and put urls like /home, /users, /files, and then go to '/' I get onEnter executed for each state. But how, I didn't enter any of them. Totally confused

Comment: If you make a jsfiddle, I'll be happy to look at the problem.